# A condition for long run boundedness for a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, upper-lower-bounds, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Suppose we have a general continuous stochastic process $X_t$ which satisfies $$\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{t \ge 0} P \left( X_t < \frac{1}{m} \right) = 0 \quad \quad \quad \textbf{(1)}$$

I want to use this to show a long run lower bound for $X$, i.e. $P-$almost surely, there exists some $m$ and $T$ such that $X_t \ge 1/m$ for every $t \ge T$.  I am not sure if $\textbf{(1)}$ implies some sort of result like this.  Formally, this is equivalent to showing $$P \left( \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{t \in [n, \infty) \cap\mathbb{Q}} \{ X_t < 1/m_n \}\right) = 0$$ for some appropriately chosen $m_n$ but I cannot show this.  I tried thinking about it in terms of Borel-Cantelli, but the $P(X_t < 1/m)$ tending to $0$ uniformly in $t$ does not suffice as far as I can gather.

Maybe I am taking the wrong approach.  Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not the case.  Let $Y \sim U(0,1)$.  For $t \in [n,n+1]$ and $j=0,...,n-2$, if $Y \in [\frac jn, \frac{j+1}n)$, define $X_{n + \frac{j+1}n} = \frac 1n$, with $X_t = 1$ for $t \in [n,n+\frac jn]$ or $t \in [n+\frac{j+2}{n},n+1]$, and linearly interpolate between.  Then for $t \ge n$, $P(X_t \ne 1) \le \frac 3n$, and for $t < n$ we have $P(X_t < \frac 1n) = 0$.  Hence for all $t \ge 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $P(X_t < \frac 1n) \le \frac 3n$, so $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{t \ge 0} P(X_t < \frac 1n) \le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac 3n = 0$.  But for all $m$ and $T$ there exists $t \ge 0$ such that $X_t < \frac 1m$.

Comment: Thanks for this example! Really is quite spectacular.  I am trying to prove the second result en route to trying to say that if $f(t)$ is a deterministic function for which $f(t) \xrightarrow{t \rightarrow \infty} \infty$, AND $X_t$ is bounded above and strictly positive then $$\frac{\log(X_t)}{f(t)} \xrightarrow{t \rightarrow \infty} 0$$ and I have no idea how to do that without a condition such as the thing I propose to show here.  I.e. I am trying to use $\textbf{(1)}$ to give a lower bound on the $\log(X_t)$ process to show it goes to $0$ since the upper bound is assumed. Is this possible?

Comment: No, this is not possible, even if $X$ is deterministic.  Let $X_t = e^{-t}$ and $f(t) = \sqrt{t}$.  Then $\frac{\log(X_t)}{f(t)} \rightarrow -\infty$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: But $X_t$ does not satisfy $\textbf{(1)}$, as $\sup_{t\ge 0} P(X_t < 1/n) = 1$ for every $n$.  I mean to say that if $\textbf{(1)}$ holds, $X_t > 0$ and bounded above, then does $\log(X_t)/f(t) \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood.  The example in my answer provides a counterexample to what you're trying to show with $f(t) = \log(t)$ for $t > 1$, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah I suppose so...since $\log(X_{n+\frac{j+1}{n}})/ \log(n+\frac{j+1}{n})$ will be arbitrarily close to $1$ for all $n$ large enough so there is a subsequence in time along which $\log(X_t)/f(t)$ does not converge to $0$.  Thank you for your help!